# How to get orientation of camera captured image in an android ported app to blackberry 10 devices?

Tags: android, camera, blackberry-10

I had ported android app to blackberry 10 devices. Camera captured image used "ExifInterface" to identify orientation of image. But it always return 0.How to identify orientation in Blackberry Z10 device while capturing image through camera.I had used the following code.

```
try 
  {
       ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
       orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
       if(orientation == android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90){
        orientation = 90;
       } else if(orientation == android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180){
        orientation = 180;
       } else if(orientation == android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270){
        orientation = 270;
       }
  } 
  catch (IOException e)
  {
      Log.error(null, e);
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Advance thanks for any help.